# how to detect page refresh or form submission in spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there any way to find in spring controller called from form submit or refresh(F5 button).

When the page refresh spring model attribute values are null , but the model attribute is not null. why is that ?

On Page refresh i need to take all model attribute values from session.

i don't want to prevent page refreshing that's not business call..

Comment: is your page a step of a web flow? If you issue a GET to a controller, you'll get exactly the same page, with the same model. I ask myself whether the problem comes from a missing server state. In few words, if you have the following web flow: PAGE1 ---> PAGE2 and PAGE2 depends on what PAGE1 does, it's obvious that you won't have it when you refresh the page (that is a plain http request), since you're entering a workflow halfway. But this is not a Spring issue. It's your business logic.

Comment: No entirely clear what you are asking (some code might help) but you can differentiate by the request method GET or POST. A request to set-up the page will typically be a GET, a form submission will typically be a POST. You can specify request methods for a `@RequestMapping`